# "Closed as not a real question" when there is an answer

Tags: discussion, moderation, closing-questions

mods, what on earth is up with that?

The question HAS AN ANSWER. : [Which muscles do I use to stand?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/69/which-muscles-do-i-use-to-stand)

.... And yet, apparently, it's not a real question.

Look - because I'm asking a question beyond your current frame of understanding does not mean it's not a real question.

Comment: Related: [When does a question stop being about martial arts?](http://meta.martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/51/when-does-a-question-stop-being-about-martial-arts) and [Recently Updated FAQ](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

Answer (score 9):

Unfitting questions that have answers, whether those answers are valuable or not, do not validate asking them. I closed your question because even after [several revisions](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/posts/69/revisions), I do not see any fundamental change in what you are asking, which is what muscles do you use to stand. It is too general and vague as it is.

It is a very basic question at its core, one that you could ask for *any* physical activity, not just martial arts. Tacking on "...in martial arts" does not create a strong connection for what you are asking. This is similar to what was asked about [running and jogging](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30/15). If you narrow the question down, make it a very specific, focused, and practical topic, then I would be willing to reopen and allow the question. I see no evidence of that here as long as the question has existed.

You asked a very similar [question about ankles](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/369/what-are-the-ankles-good-for-relative-to-stance-work-and-mobility) too that is of the same nature. The comments there also echo my sentiment here. I would also close this question as "not a real question."

With the actual [FAQ](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/faq) now in place (which, by the way, had *very* little feedback) that I aggregated after combing through the all the site's [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) questions, I made a decision to close your question because it does not fit what the Martial Arts site should be especially when it is still very young and early in beta.

Comment: Matt, please go check out the dojo and read what I wrote, and then let me know.

Comment: For reference, the start of the chat transcript is here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4133210#4133210

Comment: I have to support the closure.  The original question was openly racist.  The revised question should have been migrated to the Anatomy stack.  Frankly, that's where any question about fundamental human body parts and functions should reside.

Answer (score 2):

As the person who answered it in the first place, I'll admit that it took a lot of work to try to pull an on-topic answer from the question. At the time that it was answered, we had little direction for the site, we had no FAQ, and we had no moderators (other than community team, which is extremely busy).

As it stands now, the question is very broad in terms of our scope (our scope is a small fraction of the scope of that question), which qualifies it as "Not a Real Question".

Further, since by [your own explanation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4133210#4133210) the proposed practice is "standing practice" that would lead to an explanation, we could easily replace the phrase "martial arts" with "pilates" or "yoga" (as examples; we could include numerous other exercises, [including gymnastics or dance](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4136564#4136564)) and the answer would hold as much merit. This makes the question no different than "How do I use Excel... for martial arts?" Thus, the question is off-topic as well.

Finally, in response to a question having an answer, this should be stated and in big bold letters:

***Answers to questions are chosen by the asker; it is not up to the asker but the community to measure the validity of a question for this site.***

Comment: Wait.. How WOULD you use Excel for martial arts? I'm serious. You opened that avenue.

Comment: I don't know, but I have the benefit of being able to say this isn't the right place to discuss that problem anyhow and there's definitely a forum on which you could have that discussion [elsewhere](http://www.google.com/).

Comment: So you're telling me that martialarts.stackexchange.com is not the right place to have a discussion about martial arts? I could very well ask "Is a kubotan a useful tool (assuming training)" ... Oh wait... No, you closed that one too! So maybe I should just ask if a staff is useful.. Bah, you'd probably close that one too..

Comment: I'm sorry you took it personally. It's not; it's just about keeping a community moving in the right direction. Some questions are a good fit, some aren't. I'm sure you've been on enough SE sites to have seen that before.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a mod, but I'm no stranger to SE sites.  In general what happens in this case is that the timing was just off.  Someone slipped their answer in before the question was closed.  It could have happened while the mod was choosing the reason for closing the question.

To be fair, as asked that question was off topic.  At worst, the mod picked the wrong reason for closure.  In any case, I do agree with the closure.  The one answer you did get did their best to pull your question back on topic.

Particularly with beta sites, the mods have the unenviable task to try and keep the questions on topic.  And because this is still a beta site, "on topic" is still being refined.

Comment: .. The answer has been in there for weeks.

Comment: I'm writing stuff in the chatroom right now to explain in painstaking detail why that question was on topic.